# Mysql Query with two tables php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was wondering how to do a query with two tables in php?

I have this single query

```
?php 
$sQuery = "Select * From tb_columnas Where col_Status='activo' Order by col_ID DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sQuery, $cnxMySQL) or die(mysql_error());
$rows_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$total_rows_result = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($total_rows_result > 0){
    do {
            $id_columnas = $rows_result ['col_ID'];
            $col_Titulo = $rows_result ['col_Titulo'];
            $col_Resumen = $rows_result ['col_Resumen'];
            $col_Fecha = $rows_result ['col_Fecha'];
            $col_Autor = $rows_result ['col_Autor'];
        ?>
```

But I'd like to compare the col_Autor with au_Nombre which is in another table (tb_autores) and get au_Photo and other values from it, how can I do that?

Comment: Google MySQL JOIN. Also, the `mysql_` family of functions has been deprecated. That means they will be removed in a future version of php. You should replace them with either the [pdo](http://php.net/pdo) functions or the [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) functions

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a simple join query without using the JOIN keyword by specifying the two tables in the FROM clause and establishing a relationship in the where clause.

For example

```
   SELECT columns
   FROM table1, table2
   WHERE table1.field = table2.field
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about SQL Joins, the practicing of putting two or more tables together in an SQL statement to return data from more than 1 table. You join the tables on a common column, such as author.authorid = book.authorid. I suggest looking up JOINS on google, there are many good articles.

A great article on it: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).  Try something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_columnas JOIN tb_autores ON tb_columnas = col_Autor WHERE col_Status='activo' ORDER BY col_ID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand joins for this.

Here you will find very good explanation of the same:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html